# A word for describing a salaried job

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a paragraph comparing working and volunteering and I'm looking for a word to say that a person will be compensated if he is an employee but a volunteer won't, what is the best word that fits? **working is ______ but volunteering is not.**
I found the word 'compensative' but I don't think it's correct to use it.

Comment: Maybe _paid_ or _stipendiary_? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Diego - I agree that _paid_ is a good suggestion, but think that _stipendiary_ would be just as awkward and cumbersome as _compensative_.

Comment: @J.R. Fair enough. So _rewarded_ can fit as well.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Not *rewarded* - we often speak of the *rewards* of volunteering, which are not financial.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You wrote "salaried" in the title but not in the body. Also, you need to define what the *compensation* is. It doesn't have to be money.

Comment: Working is paid but volunteering is not. To do paid work, to do unpaid work i.e. volunteering.

Comment: I agree with Lambie that "paid" is clear and simple.  Alternately you can rewrite the sentence:  *workers are paid while volunteers are not*,  and also *you get paid for working but not for volunteering*.

Comment: Volunteer work is unpaid by definition. There isn't really a need to describe it.

Comment: You mention "compensated".  Why not use that?  Or perhaps "workers receive compensation but volunteers do not".

Comment: Would this query be a better fit for the English Language & Usage stack exchange?  http://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "remunerated" fits the bill?  From [M-W online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remunerated):  "to pay an equivalent for".  For example: "their services were generously remunerated".

"Compensated" would fit as well.

Maybe paid is the word you are looking for. Working is *paid* but volunteering is not. To do paid work, to do unpaid work i.e. volunteering. Volunteer work is unpaid by definition. There isn't really a need to describe it.